# IPhone sync/app backup - can an app do something at that time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if there is a hook in the iphone sdk that allows an app to know when its being sync'd / backed up - so that it could do something, eg connect to a website to also backup data.

I am assuming not... but I could be wrong.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris, alas, your assumption is correct. Currently, there is no support for this, but you should file a bug report with Apple requesting it!